# Doctrin 2 and Zendframework 2 after update

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

Today, using composer, i was updated my application.
My application use zfcUser / BjyAuthorize / Doctrine 2 modules.
And now, after updating, i catch this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\\ServiceManager\\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.entity_manager.orm_default' in /var/www/zf/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:518\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/zf/vendor/bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize/src/BjyAuthorize/Service/ObjectRepositoryRoleProviderFactory.php(50): Zend\\ServiceManager\\ServiceManager->get('doctrine.entity...')\n#1 [internal function]: BjyAuthorize\\Service\\ObjectRepositoryRoleProviderFactory->createService(Object(Zend\\ServiceManager\\ServiceManager), 'bjyauthorizepro...', 'BjyAuthorize\\Pr...')\n#2 /var/www/zf/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(897): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\\ServiceManager\\ServiceManager), 'bjyauthorizepro...', 'BjyAuthorize\\Pr...')\n#3 /var/www/zf/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(1027): Zend\\ServiceMan in /var/www/zf/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 518
```

Сode was not changed.

Plz, help =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the following line in your `bjyauthorize` configuration:
`'object_manager'    => 'doctrine.entity_manager.orm_default'`to

`'object_manager'    => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'`